# Internal energy of ideal gas in terms of sound speed and pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, ideal-gas

In thermodynamics two state variables can be treated as independent and any other variable can be determined from these two variables. We can assume sound speed and pressure as independent variables and internal energy, for example, can be determined in terms of sound speed and pressure. It will be good help if some one posts formula for internal energy in terms of ratio of specific heats, that is gamma, sound speed and pressure.

Comment: As far as I know the speed of sound is not a state variable

Comment: For an ideal gas, the speed of sound is $$c=\sqrt{\frac{\gamma RT}{M}}$$$\gamma$ is independent of pressure for an ideal gas. From this, you can determine the internal energy.